# How to read parts of a delimited file

Tags: php, delimited

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1028806~HDR~20110815~15-AUG-2011~C~23:10~~~~~~~
1028806~DTL~C3914A~HWP-C3914A~1000949~A~LASERJET MAINT KIT 8100/N/DN~HEWLETT PACKARD~2659~12~0~0~475.75~658.75~0~3~Y~2~~2~475.75~5~~~009088336~~3179~10.60~N~8.25~8.50~20.50~~088698601976~44103109~6A~20030627~NNY~~A~S~~~~~~N~~~~~~20.50~8.50~8.25~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1028806~DTL~70023301~OKI-70023301~1002121~A~OKILAN 6020E+ 10/100BASE-TX ETHERNET EXT~OKI PRINTING SOLUTIONS~2703~0~0~0~55.17~80.00~0~0~Y~0~~0~55.17~0~~~009117000~~2160~2.79~N~8.00~8.75~14.00~~000000180016~44101700~ACC-IMPACT~19950723~NNY~~A~S~~~~~~N~~~~~~14.00~8.75~8.00~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1028806~DTL~PRO7T~APC-PRO7T~1003150~A~Professional-grade Protection for Computers and Electronics~AMERICAN POWER CONVERSION~20664~7~0~0~21.60~36.00~0~0~Y~0~~0~21.60~7~~~008112000~~4400~2.00~N~1.90~6.90~12.40~~731304000181~39121610~SURG~19950723~NNY~~A~S~~~~~~N~~~~~~12.40~6.90~1.90~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1028806~DTL~PER7~APC-PER7~1003418~A~Surge suppressor ( external ) / 7 output connector(s)~AMERICAN POWER CONVERSION~20664~496~50~0~9.30~15.25~0~3~Y~86~~363~9.30~44~~~008118000~~4400~1.85~N~2.10~6.90~11.50~~731304000112~39121610~SURG~20011025~NNY~~A~S~~~~~~N~~~~~~11.50~6.90~2.10~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1028806~DTL~PRO7~APC-PRO7~1003761~A~APC SurgeArrest Professional - Surge suppressor ( external ) - AC 120 V - 7 outp~AMERICAN POWER CONVERSION~20664~88~0~0~17.59~30.00~0~0~Y~12~~52~17.59~24~~~008112000~~4400~1.95~N~2.25~7.50~12.25~~731304000174~39121610~SURG~19950723~NNY~~A~S~~~~~~N~~~~~~12.25~7.50~2.25~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I need to use a script to read certain parts of each line (the bold parts):

1028806~DTL~**C3914A**~HWP-C3914A~1000949~A~**LASERJET MAINT KIT 8100/N/DN**~HEWLETT PACKARD~2659~12~0~0~475.75~658.75~0~3~Y~2~~2~475.75~5~~~009088336~~3179~10.60~N~8.25~8.50~20.50~~088698601976~44103109~6A~20030627~NNY~~A~S~~~~~~N~~~~~~20.50~8.50~8.25~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The file has over 300k items so going through manually is not an option, so how can I get a script to read only these parts when I don't know how long the part # and descriptions are? While ignoring all the other ~ characters.

Thanks

Comment: Are there patterns you could look for? I'm not even sure how you'd do it manually. How do you know when you've found them?

Comment: Looks like you want whatever's after the third and seventh tilde. I'm sure there's a PHP way of doing this (explode or something) and I'm looking forward to finding out exactly what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/function.fgetcsv.php) can help here, a little more memory-conservative than loading the whole file up at once and `explode()`'ing all the lines into a giant array.

```
if (($handle = fopen("/path/to/file", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "~")) !== FALSE) {
       echo $data[2] . " " . $data[6];
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// read the file
$lines = file('file.txt');

// loop through each line
foreach($lines as $line){
    // separate the parts by the ~ delimiter up to the second bold part
    // ignoring the rest of ~
    $parts = explode('~', $line, 7);
    echo $parts[2]; // output first bold part
    echo $parts[6]; // output second bold part
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can explode on tilde:

```
$fields = explode('~', $line);
$part_num = $fields[2];
$desc = $fields[6];
```